# Eject usb drive from Windows Service c#

Tags: c#, windows, service, windows-services

I have been developing windows service which needs to Eject USB drive in some cases.
I have been using the  [code project sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13530/Eject-USB-disks-using-C)

Its working fine in desktop/Winforms application but not in the Windows service.
the service is running as LocalSystem account.

The `CreateFile` funtion is returning invalid handle always, in the windows service. Is there any limitation for `CreateFile` to be used in Service, or is it restricted because it is running on LocalSystem account.

If so is there any alternate options?

Comment: What is the result of [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) method after CreateFile?

Comment: @balayan thanks for the clue.. the Last error is 32 (ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION).. But it happens only for devices with FAT32 filesystem , For NTFS its working fine. So does it has any dependecy with the filesystem?

Comment: Could you show the args for CreateFile WinAPI method?

Comment: `CreateFile(driveLetter, GENERICREAD, 0, IntPtr.Zero, OPENEXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);` where `driveLetter` will be like \\.\F:

Comment: Try to use share mode: FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE

Comment: @balayan Thank you so much. it worked..!
Is this the limiation for FAT32?